# Is is possible to develop for windows, in C++, without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm aspiring to work in real-time 3D graphics. I work almost exclusively in C++, with a healthy smattering of win32. Realistically, do I have any sane alternatives?

Comment: Hatred is rarely a carefully researched position. Especially when you prefix what would normally be a decent question with a rant (71% of your question based on line count).

Comment: Good one, @Shy, let's poke the troll with a stick to see what happens :-)

Comment: Let's be fair though, the IDE *is* ridiculously slow, and makes some very strong assumptions about how you work and how your projects are structured, which sometimes drives me mad. But yes, it's *also* a fantastic IDE in many ways. Examples of its suckage, please? :)

Comment: It's not that things are 'offensive', but more of a general impenetrability. When starting a new project, for example, I can go spelunking blindly through the options until it magically works, or I can copy-paste an old project and delete out the code. Both suck. Bleah, sorry for rantiness.

Comment: You're not the first to get a bit hung up on this (although most people figure it out with less than "hundreds of hours" of "careful research" ;)
But ask it as a separate question, so others can find it and benefit from it as well.

Comment: I will go out on a limb here and say that the "blind spelunking," magical working", and "copy-paste" have little if anything to do with your IDE.  When you do get things working, do you do a postmortem, figure out what REALLY went wrong or just plow onwards?

Comment: The VS C++ project templates are not straightforward, unfortunately. They tend to clutter your files with a lot of default code that no one ever uses, and which throws precompiled headers and other nonstandard complexities at the beginner who just picked the default options.

Comment: VS is far from perfect. It is very slow to load, can be slow to update intellisense database especially for c/c++, it has tendency to crash occasionally, it can missing in action while your in the middle of typing in some code, only for it to come back a few seconds later. It could be a lot better.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the MSVC compiler without the IDE. That's probably your best bet. It's a good compiler, and it is the de facto standard for Windows development.

There is definitely nothing wrong with ditching the IDE and simply using the compiler.

I believe the MSVC compiler can be used from the Code::Blocks IDE with no problems.
Alternatively, invoking the compiler from the command-line is a tried and true approach too.

Comment: Could you also use MSBuild, or XBuild if you're developing MONO, and the Windows SDK to achieve teh same thing without even downloading and installing Visual Studio?

Comment: It depends. In recent releases, the MSVC++ compiler has *only* been available as part of Visual Studio. The .NET compilers, on the other hand, have been made available separately (I can't remember if they're part of the Windows SDK, or a separate package). MSBuild works fine with that compiler out of the box. If you want to use a third-party compiler (for example as part of Mono), you *can* still use MSBuild, but you'll have to write the necessary configuration and extensions for it to correctly invoke the "foreign" compiler

Comment: The information is no longer accurate. Starting with Visual Studio 2017 the [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) are now available as a separate download. [Introducing the Visual Studio Build Tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/) has more information.

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse: [http://www.eclipse.org/](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Code::Blocks is pretty cool: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: And of course [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/) with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)!

Answer (score 6):

Depends...

Cygwin/Mingwin gives you a compiler.  Qt or wxWidgets gives you a GUI toolkit that's easy to use and both are portable.

I agree with the question though.  Visual Studio is a pig.  Its debugger is pretty nice, but the rest is a pig to work with (particularly coming from a OSS background where the tools don't generally try to lock you in).

You could also look at nmake and calling the VC++ compiler tools directly from the command line.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by: "try to lock you in". I have the feeling I can let VS do whatever I want, to me VS seems very flexible and moldable.

Comment: VS is great, so long as "whatever I want" fits with "whatever Microsoft wants".  It can be customised but you're stuck with its interface, its project file format, its compiler, etc, and it's a lot of work to build your software if VS isn't available.  Makefile-based projects using standard compiler tools make a lot more sense, particularly if you ever forsee taking your program away from Windows.

Answer (score 5):

We use VC++ as a compiler / linker but use [Jam](http://www.perforce.com/jam/jam.html) to drive the builds. The actual Visual Studio is only used as a debugger. The benefit is that once we set up Jam to build a project in Windows, it takes minimal effort (frequently **none**) to get it working for Unix.

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus IDE](http://www.zeusedit.com) works just fine as a *MSVC* alternative. It can even import *MSVC* project and solution files.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but I'd like to add that in 2018 there finally begins to show up a viable alternative that is good enough to promise emancipation from the monopoly of VS on Windows C++ development:

- [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) as editor, with the following plugins:

  - [EasyClangComplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EasyClangComplete), a decent (like, *just working*) replacement for Intellisense;
  - [optionally] [Clang Format](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Clang%20Format), for much more flexible source formatting experience than MS would ever come up with;
- [Clang-cl](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html) as a wrapper around Clang compiler aimed for [maximum MSVC compatibility](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html).

Unfortunately, Microsoft Build Tools are still needed for standard library headers, but the download size is nothing compared to the whole VS behemoth. The upside is that Clang-cl picks them up automagically and Build Tools somehow don't mandate that you let their executables go online to *sign in* and *activate your free license* yet!

Setting this all up to a working configuration is a bit more complicated than slapping together a VS project/solution, but it's totally worth it. As a bonus, setting things up manually might give you a better understanding of what goes on under the hood of an IDE.

One thing to miss might be the superb VS debugger... Well, if you're ready to break habits, the open source [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/) might come to the rescue, ability to view and step through source code via .pdb files included (and yes, Clang [can generate them now!](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html)).

**Update:** As of 2019, a much better and future-proof alternative to EasyClangComplete is using [Clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/Installation.html) via [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) plugin.

Comment: How to install clang on windows using the visual studio build tools
https://gist.github.com/InNoHurryToCode/955d63db0d79699fed63fe18eeebf17e

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, but it's just a lot easier to use Microsoft's IDE to develop for a Microsoft operating system.  When in Rome...

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE comes with the MinGW C++ compiler and support for wxWidgits. The IDE is pretty minimalist which may or may not be what you are looking for - I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

Very possible, [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products) is your friend. [Qt Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/qt-creator) is in RC stage too so something to look forward to. Until then you can use it with something like [Code::Blocks.](http://www.codeblocks.org/) Code::Blocks itself is a great environment alone, and also has a lot of support for wxWidgets. If you're just looking for an IDE change, as previously mentioned, Code::Blocks can use compilers from other IDE's as well.

-John

Answer (score 1):

[Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) I have found very useful, and free :)

Comment: It's buggy, hasn't been maintained for years, and even when it *was* maintained, it wasn't worth using compared to the competition.

Comment: I wish it was maintained, I cut my teeth on this IDE back in the day.

Answer (score 1):

SlickEdit (or a number of other editors that support ctags or something similar) makes for a pretty decent 'IDE'.

You can use these editors with makefiles (or other build tools) to drive pretty much whatever compiler you want (MVCS, mingw, Comeau, Digital Mars, whatever).

A couple employers ago, that's exactly what we did.  We used MS compilers driven by makefiles and the main editor used was SlickEdit. We used the Debugging Tools for Windows package for debugging (a lot of what we did was kernel-mode).  Worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

[Wascana Desktop Developer](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/) is a distribution of Eclipse CDT configured specifically for developing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx), and the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) a look over. You could also use [XBuild](http://mono-project.com/Porting_MSBuild_Projects_To_XBuild), but that is more MONO specific. Mind you, MSBuild, and XBuild are just automation tools, so you'd be spending more time with Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure to receive a lot of flak for this, but I find C++Builder to be a much easier IDE/compiler to develop Windows C++ apps with than MSVC.  It may not be the cheapest solution, or have all the same bells+whistles, or be the most language-compliant (its 32bit compiler does not support C++11 yet, but its 64bit compiler does), but you can't really beat its visual UI designer and 3rd party component market.